# /usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory

Tags: debian

Today I got this email from my debian server:

```
test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )

/etc/cron.daily/man-db:
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/local/share/man/man1/: Permission denied
```

Can me tell somebody what does it mean? I didn't change any permissions:

```
drw---S--- 2 root staff 4096 Jun 28 14:05 man1
```

P.S> Directory /usr/local/share/man/man1 contains 1 file: csf.1. Yesterday (Jun28) CSF/LFT was updated automatically. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: The output is: drw---S--- 2 root staff 4096 Jun 28 14:05 /usr/local/share/man/man1

Comment: This directory contains file csf.1. Yesterday CSF/LFD was updated automatically.

Comment: What is CFS/LFD? Wait. I found it.

Comment: On my second server the same story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that whatever process automatically updated that CPanel thingy, did it under a restricted `umask`, (077), preventing the group or others having any permissions on it.

To solve the specific problem reported by `cron`, it should be enough to run:

```
 # chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/share/man
```

However, it is very likely that other directories have broken permissions too. Note that you only noticed it because some cron task failed.

You need to find out why you don't have control over the updates on your own system.

Comment: Thanks. I have control over the updates. CSF/LFD is set to update automatically and it updates 1-2 times per month. Don't know why this update created problems with permissions. On my 2 servers the same problem.

Comment: P.S. /usr/local/share/man has correct permissions. Problem was: /usr/local/share/man/man1

Comment: Hence the `-R` flag